# Recognize that in which direction a control dragged

Tags: xcode, ios4, iphone

Imagine that i drag an ImageView in TouchesMoved,how can i recognize that in which direction i dragged it from code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store a temporary Point from `touchesBegan`. Add a iVar in "YourImageView" interface.

```
@interface YourImageView : UIImageView
{
    CGPoint previousPt;
    //Other iVars.
}
@end 

@implementation YourImageView

- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   
    previousPt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
}

- (void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    const CGPoint p = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.view];
    if (previousPt.x > p.x)
    {
        //Dragged right to left
    }
    else if  (previousPt.x < p.x)
    {
        //Dragged left to right
    }
    else
    {
        //no move
    }
    //Do the same thing for y-direction
}
```

I would extract a method out of it. But I hope you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you subtract the old position from the new position of the ImageView, then you will get a direction vector. If you want a unit vector, just normalize it.